# Harnack's curve theorem for zero sets of real trig polynomials in two variables?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, trigonometric-series

Is there a result like [Harnack's curve theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harnack's_curve_theorem) for real trig polynomials which gives bounds for the number of connected components the zero set can have in terms of the degree?

More specifically, let $C$ be the curve in $[0,1]^2$ given by the level set $f(x,y) = 0$ where

$$f(x,y) = a_{0,0} + \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{l=1}^n a_{k,l} \cos(2 \pi (kx + ly)) + b_{k,l} \sin(2 \pi (kx + ly)),\text{ with }a_{k,l},b_{k,l}\in \mathbb{R},$$

and let $c$ be the number of connected components of $C$. Then can we establish a bound of the form $c = O(n^2)$ or something of the like?